# HBITMAP *Bitmap to .net Bitmap

Tags: c#, c++

I have a Dll and the header file for it, and I'm trying to create a COM wrapper in C++ to use in C#.
For most of functions it was very simple since they were returning `int` or `string`.

I have this struct in the header file.

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetBMP( 
            int Width,
            int Height,
            HBITMAP *Bitmap) = 0;
```

My problem is that since I'm way out of my league with C++ I don't know how to convert the `HBITMAP` to something more appropriated to .net style

Thanks in advance, and please forgive me if wrote stupid things

UPDATE:
I tried something like this :

```
HBITMAP GetBMP(int Width, int Height)
{

    HBITMAP bm = 0; 
    m_piHelper->GetBMP(Width,Height,&bm);   
    return bm ;

}
```

The problem obviously is after that in c# how convert from 'HBITMAP__*' to 'System.IntPtr to use it with bitmap.fromHbitmap

Comment: The `[DllImport]` C# declaration for `GetBMP` is the place where you declare the third parameter as `out IntPtr`.

Comment: no im not importing the dll in c# im trying to write c++ wrapper

Comment: Then you confused all us. "Managed wrapper" is something you write in C#. If you are writing a C++ wrapper, that might be a COM wrapper. I have edited your question to reflect this. Please feel free to amend the edit as appropriate. (Maybe you *are* using managed C++?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter should be `out IntPtr`.

Then you can create an additional function that will call `GetBMP` and then call [`Bitmap.FromHbitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k061we7x.aspx) to return a bitmap. Such function must then `DeleteObject` the original `hbitmap`.

Answer (score 0):

You should perhaps try System.IntPtr.